# Got nil on creating new ViewController's instance

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I create new ViewController (which is custom AlertController) after finishing some operation in other ViewController and after that have error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Here is the code:

```
    class CustomAlertController: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var okButton: UIButton!

internal func loadFromStoryboard() -> CustomAlertController! {
        let alertsStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Alerts", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let alertControllerStoryboardVC = alertsStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomAlertController") as! CustomAlertController
        return alertControllerStoryboardVC
    }

class func showAlert(controller: UIViewController? = nil, title: String, message: String, okTitle: String, completion: ()->Void = {}) {
        let customAlertVC = CustomAlertController().loadFromStoryboard()
        customAlertVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom

        let localTransitioningDelegate = AlertTransitioningDelegate()
        customAlertVC.transitioningDelegate = localTransitioningDelegate

        customAlertVC.titleLabel.text = title
        customAlertVC.messageLabel.text = message
        customAlertVC.okButton.titleLabel?.text = okTitle


        if controller != nil {
            controller?.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
            controller?.presentViewController(customAlertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            print("something went wrong, friend")
        }
    }
```

And in another ViewController I have:

```
CustomAlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Success!", message: "Operation done", okTitle: "OK")
```

The problem is **titleLabel** and other properties that have to be set are nil.

Any help would be useful.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBOutlets are nil because `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` does not load the view and subviews - this happens when the alertController is presented.  Just add variables to your `CustomAlertController` class:

```
var title = ""
var message = ""
var okButtonTitle = ""
```

and set those values rather than trying to access the IBOutlets:

```
customAlertVC.title = title
customAlertVC.message = message
customAlertVC.okButtonTitle = okTitle
```

Then override `viewDidLoad` to configure the labels/buttons with these values:

```
self.titleLabel.text = title
self.messageLabel.text = message
self.okButton.setTitle(okButtonTitle, forState: .Normal)
```

Note also that you should use `.setTitle(, forState: .Normal)` rather than setting the title label directly.